# "Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the libswiftCore.dylib plug-in"

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I have Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 in the same Macbook, but then I updated the Xcode 7 to 7.1 and now I can't open the Xcode 6.4 version.

```
Process:               Xcode [13139]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.4 (7720)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7720000000000000~8
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [13139]
User ID:               502

PlugIn Path:             /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libswiftCore.dylib
PlugIn Version:          2.1 (700.1.101.6)

Date/Time:             2015-10-23 10:51:23.902 -0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1021)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        3C65E0B9-2018-8B23-3825-C5EB4D6161BE

Sleep/Wake UUID:       79EE1FEB-DB8C-44E2-9C3B-F7C7B6C44EB5

Time Awake Since Boot: 19000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6900 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6E35b

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff851dafb2 strlen + 18
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000119247aac _buildDemanglingForNominalType(swift::Demangle::Node::Kind, swift::Metadata const*, swift::NominalTypeDescriptor const*) + 44
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000119245cc5 _buildDemanglingForMetadata(swift::Metadata const*) + 133
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000119247b7c _buildDemanglingForNominalType(swift::Demangle::Node::Kind, swift::Metadata const*, swift::NominalTypeDescriptor const*) + 252
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000119245cc5 _buildDemanglingForMetadata(swift::Metadata const*) + 133
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001192459bc swift_getGenericClassObjCName + 28
6   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001191975dd 0x118ffe000 + 1676765
7   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000011923bdd8 (anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* llvm::function_ref<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* ()>::callback_fn<swift::swift_getGenericMetadata::$_0>(long) + 24
8   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000011923bce0 swift::MetadataCache<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>::addMetadataEntry(swift::EntryRef<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>, ConcurrentList<swift::MetadataCache<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>::EntryPair>&, llvm::function_ref<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* ()>) + 128
9   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000119238488 swift_getGenericMetadata + 504
10  libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000011923851d swift_getGenericMetadata3 + 29
11  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000119519226 _TZFe0_Rq_Ss8Hashable_10FoundationVSs10Dictionary26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCu0_Rq_S__fMGS1_q_q0__FTCSo12NSDictionary6resultRGSqGS1_q_q0____T_ + 54
12  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001195190ed _TF10Foundation32_convertNSDictionaryToDictionaryu0_Rq_Ss8Hashable_FGSqCSo12NSDictionary_GVSs10Dictionaryq_q0__ + 61
13  ca.nri.ColorSenseRainbow        0x0000000118dce1ad _TTSf4g_n___TZFC17ColorSenseRainbow17ColorSenseRainbow13pluginDidLoadfMS0_FCSo8NSBundleT_ + 189 (ColorSenseRainbow.swift:33)
14  ca.nri.ColorSenseRainbow        0x0000000118dcc6f5 _TToZFC17ColorSenseRainbow17ColorSenseRainbow13pluginDidLoadfMS0_FCSo8NSBundleT_ + 37
15  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000118530075 __46-[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:forDomain:]_block_invoke + 147
16  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e5ff972 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint + 83
17  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011852fd9c -[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:forDomain:] + 1041
18  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011852f831 __46-[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPluginsInDomain:]_block_invoke + 621
19  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e5e689d -[DVTPlugInManager _allowNonApplePlugInsFromDescriptors:error:] + 476
20  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e5e6b1e -[DVTPlugInManager _checkNonApplePlugIns] + 239
21  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e5e6b94 -[DVTPlugInManager initializePlugIns:] + 27
22  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010f081634 _IDEInitializeOtherPlugInStuff + 175
23  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010f082a0c IDEInitialize + 3533
24  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f667bdc -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 710
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87c2e45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87b1e634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
27  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90092aa1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
28  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e5db998 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 162
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83229e57 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 440
30  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010eb7f952 -[DVTApplication finishLaunching] + 149
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83229921 -[NSApplication run] + 128
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff831a6244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8fe005c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c9c7232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff822cd26e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c9c694a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8af043dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c9c694a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8af043dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c9c694a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8af043dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c9c694a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8af043dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000119245c87  rbx: 0xc9854800101ab30d  rcx: 0xc9854800101ab30d  rdx: 0xc9854800101ab30d
  rdi: 0xc9854800101ab300  rsi: 0x0000000000000007  rbp: 0x00007fff517d81e0  rsp: 0x00007fff517d81e0
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x00000000fffffff0  r10: 0x0000000000000002  r11: 0x00007fe83d300000
  r12: 0x0000000119284f20  r13: 0x000000011919c970  r14: 0x0000000000000007  r15: 0x00007fff517d85d0
  rip: 0x00007fff851dafb2  rfl: 0x0000000000010286  cr2: 0x000000011919c978

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     13
```

Comment: try restarrting your mac after the xcode upgrade.

Comment: I already tried and did not work. :/

Comment: same thing happening for me, but I am not trying to open an old version. Trying to open up xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One or more plugins need to be removed from this directory:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/

**To Fix:**

Open the directory noted above and temporarily remove one or more of the plugins found.

**Note:**

Running the following command in Terminal as a non-sudo user will show the plugins impacting the startup:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Sample errors produced after running the code in Terminal

```
2015-10-01 09:04:07.052 Xcode[860:42364] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 0420B86A-AA43-4792-9ED0-6FE0F2B16A13 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/SwiftCodeSnippets.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2015-10-01 09:04:07.054 Xcode[860:42364] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 0420B86A-AA43-4792-9ED0-6FE0F2B16A13 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/CocoaControlsPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2015-10-01 09:04:07.054 Xcode[860:42364] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 0420B86A-AA43-4792-9ED0-6FE0F2B16A13 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/BBUUtilitiesTuckAway.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar issue fixed for my **Xcode 7.2.1** by **restarting my Mac**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and my fix was to delete all the subfolders in Xcode's derived data directory.  Xcode automatically rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing libMainThreadChecker.dylib file as:

```
rm -r /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib
```